# How can I build a permanent shelter in very remote area?

Tags: building

I can haul material with large 4 wheel ATV.  Was thinking about one of those 7x7 resin sheds, but want to explore less expensive options for a camp get-away on property I own.  3 season use, but only for a few days at a time, including sleeping.

I probably intend to build the base out of pressure treated wood as if I was going to build the shed.

Comment: for free: dugouts, clay blocks, and log cabins come to mind.

Comment: Depends what is on the land, and how much work you want to put in to it.  Trees, stones, and dirt could all be used to build something.

Comment: Can gravel and sand be obtained locally?

Comment: Wickiup, wattle-and-daub, log cabin...or the ever so handy self-portable chicken-legged hut (helps to be a witch for that one.) More "modern conventionally," for that short a timeframe, platform and tent.

Comment: Ok, log cabin idea has some merit!  Gravel and sand are not on the property.  Ecnerwal - platform and tent is definitely under consideration as well.  I was also thinking of a pop-up hunting blind, a large one 112in by 112in would work on the platform.

Comment: corrugated iron, plywood, or other construction panels,

Comment: @jasen great ideas - any thoughts on the corrugated iron ?  I am going to build the base as if it were a shed out of 2x6x12 pressure treated with a plywood platform.  How to proceed from there with the corrugated iron ?  What on-centers and corner posts?

Answer (score 3):

Corrugatesd (or other profile) "iron" (ie. sheet steel) skin, over 2x4 frame cross-braced with metal strap.

You want one or two courses of blocking to give an attachment point for the sheets.

The floor (and thus roof) seems small enough that you can eschew rafters and build a skillion roof with the iron laid directly on purlins which rest on the side walls.  2x4 is probably big enough for these.

Fix with nails or screws (nails are much easier if you don't have electricity).

I have not consulted a framing manual, so the above sizes are guesses. you should check the tables for your wind, snow, and seizmic requirements.